# How to pass variables to angular @HostBinding(variable_here)?

Tags: angular

The following is a directive I'm using to define width of elements.
The idea is to input type of width so that the directive can bind to it accordingly.

So this will bind to either min width or max width of the element. I'm doing this way because this is reusable in different places. ie there are occassions min width is required & in some other cases max width is required.

```
@Input() widthInput: 'min' | 'max'

 @HostBinding(`style.${widthInput}.px`) width = 10
```

But when I do this I'm getting an error that cannot read property widthInput of undefined && args to hostbinding must be a string.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: pretty sure this isn't going to work as host bindings aren't dynamic

Comment: How can this be made possible? so that the code doesnot get repeated in different places.

Comment: this just looks like it's better accomplished with css tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get dynamic `@HostBinding` you need to create dynamic getter, i.e.:

```
@HostBinding('style.width') get elementWidth() {
   return `${this.widthInput}.px`;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Most of  the time people donwvotes saying that it is not possible. But someone will help. Thankyou.